# Golang: Read buffered input as signed 16bit ints

Tags: go, buffer, wav

I am trying to read a buffered stream of signed 16 bit integers (wav format), but the bufio.Read method only accepts an array of bytes. My question is a 2-parter:

1. Can I preformat the byte stream into a buffered int16 array?
2. If I can't, whats the best way of post-processing the byte array into int16 array? My initial thought is to use tmp arrays and keep pushing/processing them, but I was curious if there was a more idiomatic way of doing this?

   ```
   package main

   import (
        "bufio"
        "io"
        "log"
        "os/exec"
   )

   func main() {

       app := "someapp"

       cmd := exec.Command(app)
       stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
       r := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
       if err != nil {
           log.Fatal(err)
       }
       if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
           log.Fatal(err)
       }

       //"someapp" outputs signed 16bit integers (little endian))
       buf := make([]byte, 0, 4*1024)

       for {
           n, err := r.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])    //r.Read only accepts type []byte
           buf = buf[:n]
           if n == 0 {
               if err == nil {
                   continue
               }
               if err == io.EOF {
                   break
               }
               log.Fatal(err)
           }

           log.Printf("%x\n", buf)
           //process buf here

           if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
               log.Fatal(err)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue at hand, but your code doesn't follow the semantics of [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). (It turns out [`bufio.Buffer`'s](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) implementation is documented to be more strict, but in general it's best to assume any `io.Reader`).

Answer (score 4):

When working with IO, you always work with `[]byte`s, there's no way to substitute that with `[]int16`, or pre-format that as `int16`s, it's always a stream of bytes.

You can look at the [`encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package to decode this stream.

```
// to get the first uint16 as i
i := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(buf[:2])
```

You can then iterate through the buf as needed.

You can also use [`binary.Read`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) to read directly from the `io.Reader`.

```
var i uint16
for {
    err := binary.Read(r, binary.LittleEndian, &i)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

It may worth noting the simplicity of what needs to be done. Each `uint16` is created via:

```
func (littleEndian) Uint16(b []byte) uint16 {
    return uint16(b[0]) | uint16(b[1])<<8
}
```

Comment: Looks like I should iterate over the array [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/YPw2j8cc3d)? There isn't an int16 method for binary.Read, so I lose sign, but that can be converted when I need it.

Comment: @smileybone: Yes, that works, just check that you always have 2 bytes to work with at the end of the slice. There's no Int16 method because you just convert it from a uint16 (the library does this internally when needed, look at the binary.Read function source)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`encoding/binary.Read`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) to fill an `[]int16` directly from your reader, although technically the answer to your first question is still no (check the source of `binary.Read`, it reads the data to a `[]byte` first).