# Convert an unsigned byte stream to signed bytestream Golang

Tags: java, go, bytestream

What is the best way to convert an bytestream to a bytestream slice in Golang? Currently I'm trying to replicate a java program in golang and I believe I am having some issues with the fact that java reads the bytestream as a signed value, whereas golang treats it as an unsigned value.

When I print in Java note the negative values are different. Positive are the same:

> Java:
>
> 8|**-8**|**-58**|-61|-56|-113|42|16|-64|2|24|-16|1
>
> Golang:
>
> 8|**248**|**198**|195|200|143|42|16|192|2|2|240|1

Currently, my implementation right in GO looks like:

```
//open the file with os.open
//create new reader and unzip it

//reads from zip file and returns an array of bytes associated with it.
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fz)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
//reflect.TypeOf shows this is a []uint8
//I want this to be a []int8 (so signed).
```

In Java the implementation was pretty much:

```
  //create buffer reader
  //create input stream
  //create datainput stream
  //use the .Read function to get the values required.
```

I didn't see any easy way to typecast it quickly to a signed int (maybe I'm wrong). I could try to iterate through the entire slice, converting each value to a signed int, but that approach seems rather messy. It would also require me to operate on each. Is there a cleaner way of converting the slice?

Comment: The top answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12357865/4740606 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28949063/4740606 might be helpful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to clear: both Java and Go reads the data the same way from files.

Files are series of binary data grouped by 8 bits, which we call a *byte*. This *byte* is 8 bits, how you interpret it is entirely up to you.

Both Go and Java will read the same 8-bit groups, but Java will store it in a Java `byte` type which is a *signed* type, and Go will store it in a Go `byte` type which is *unsigned*. But both will have the same 8 bits, the read data will be equal:

```
var b byte = 248
var i int8 = -8
fmt.Printf("%x %x\n", b, byte(i))
```

Output:

```
f8 f8
```

Should you need to interpret the read 8 bits as a signed value, simply use a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
data := []byte{8, 248, 198}
for _, v := range data {
    fmt.Println(int8(v))
}
```

Output (same as the Java output):

```
8|-8|-58|
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4nRJ5zQ8IE).

Should you worry about performance (because of type conversions)? Absolutely not. `byte` -> `int8` conversion has no runtime cost, as both have the same memory layout (that is, 8 bits = 1 byte), and the conversion just tells to interpret those 8 bits differently.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unsafe.Pointer` if you know **exactly** what you are doing. Because as its name suggests, it is unsafe. Therefore, it will blow up if you use it unwisely.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    unsigned := make([]uint8, 0)
    unsigned = append(unsigned, 128)
    unsigned = append(unsigned, 255)

    signed := *(*[]int8)(unsafe.Pointer(&unsigned))
    fmt.Printf("%d : %d\n", signed[0], unsigned[0])
    fmt.Printf("%d : %d\n", signed[1], unsigned[1])
}
// -128 : 128
// -1 : 255
```

You can find this example on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LHTl-Io3CY)

Comment: This seems to work, though the unsafe operations scares me a little bit. Will play with this to make sure I understand this completely

Answer (score 1):

The unsafe answer above is perfectly fine, however it wouldn't work on appengine.

Here's the safe version:

```
signed := make([]int8, len(unsigned))
for i, v := range unsigned {
    signed[i] = int8(v)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/XF6RsLkm0m)